# What is the right connection string to connect to a SQL Server via Reverse Proxy with mod_proxy(<Location "/testDB/">)]?

Tags: sql-server, apache, connection-string, mod-proxy

The Reverse Proxy Config is:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1:443>
    <Location "/testDB/">                
        ProxyPassReverse "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:1433"
        ProxyPass "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:1433"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1/testDB/,443;Database=databaseName;Integrated Security=false;User ID=userid;Password=password;Connection Timeout=30;
```

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)
```

If I try `curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1/testDB/` in powershell the SQl server logs an error. So the server configuration should be working.

I tried serveral diffrent combinations. The configuration is necessary because an internal security rule is that port 1433 must be closed to the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `curl xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1/testDB/` is making a HTTP request. The SqlConnection object doesn't know how to make HTTP requests.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks. The curl command was just a test to see if a request is forwarded to the RDS instance. The SQL Server succesfully logged the failed connection attempt. So the problem should not be a firewall, ...